# Hide EAV custom field

Tags: magento2, eav, eav-attributes

I've create a custom attribute for the customer_address.

It is at **backend**:

```
$customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
$customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'my_id', [
    'label' => 'My label',
    'input' => 'text',
    'type' => 'int',
    'source' => '',
    'required' => false,
    'position' => 1000,
    'visible' => false,
    'system' => false,
    'is_used_in_grid' => false,
    'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
    'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
    'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
]);
$attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'my_id')
        ->addData([
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer_address']
]);
$attribute->save();
```

But the textbox is still appears on the forms where `Address` is.

Why?

I thought this will solve my problem:

```
'visible' => false,
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solutoin is the end of the my answer**

Ok, finally I've debugged the whole `addAtribute` process.

The key is good: `visible => false`

The code here is not so consistent, see this in:

`module-customer\Model\ResourceModel\Setup\PropertyMapper.php`

```
public function map(array $input, $entityTypeId)
{
    return [
        'is_visible' => $this->_getValue($input, 'visible', 1),
        ....
```

It is wait for key `visible`, and transform it to `is_visible` don't ask me why.

In my case, the problem was that I've deleted the key from the `eav_attribute` table, downgrade the `setup_module` run `setup:upgrade` but no change.

This is because it has stored this in the `customer_eav_attribute` table.

For debugugging first I set it to `true` so it stuck there.

So I need to delete from there, repeat the whole process and after this it works.

**EDIT**

When I told works, I meant that the value of the `is_visible` in the table now is `0`. Hurray!

:( Field appears. Need to dig deeper.

**Solution**

Facepalm. It was so obvious for me that `visible` means visibility.

The solition is to change the type `hidden`.

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'my_id', [
        ...
        'input' => 'hidden',
        ...
    ]);
```